# Data Constructor - Same Types

Tags: haskell

Given the following data type:

```
data JoinList m a = Empty
                  | Single m a
                  | Append m (JoinList m a) (JoinList m a)
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Using `ghci`, I did:

```
*JoinList> :t Single 5 3
Single 5 3 :: (Num m, Num a) => JoinList m a
```

Why are two `Num` types required here? Since both types are `Num`, then why couldn't we have:

`Single 5 3 :: (Num m) => JoinList m m`

Comment: `Num` is a class, not a data type. `Int` is an instance, and `Float` is also an instance. Both instances don't have to be the same.

Comment: The short answer is: There are two Num constraints for the same reason there are two type variables in your ADT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a given they're the same type.

You allow the types to vary in the definition of JoinList and you didn't assert 5 and 3 were the same Num in a type signature.

```
GHCi, version 7.8.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> :l joinlist.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling JoinList         ( joinlist.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: JoinList.
Prelude> :t Single 5 3
Single 5 3 :: (Num a, Num m) => JoinList m a
Prelude> let same = Single 5 3 :: Num a => JoinList a a
Prelude> :t same
same :: Num a => JoinList a a
```

Because the literals are polymorphic Num values, they could be two different concrete types under the hood.

```
Prelude> let diff = Single 5 3 :: JoinList Int Float
Prelude> diff
Single 5 3.0
Prelude> :t diff
diff :: JoinList Int Float
```